# How do I assign a zero for a document with zero matches?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a json file like this:

```
{
 "ID": 1,
 "FIELD1": "1",
 "Comments": "brakes, good, condition.  ",
 "FIELD3": "73"
},
{
 "ID": 2,
 "FIELD1": "2",
 "Comments": "Smooth, total overall very good",
 "FIELD3": "33"
}, 

{
 "ID": 3,
 "FIELD1": "20",
 "Comments": "Nothing",
 "FIELD3": "3"
 }
```

I used the aggregate function to count the number of words (such as good), and get this output:

```
_id                                   Count
brakes, good condition                  3
Smooth, total overall very good         4
```

My question is there are comments that return a zero match. How do i get this output:

```
_id                                   Count
brakes, good condition                  3
Smooth, total overall very good         4
Nothing                                 0
```

My query is this:

```
  db.test.aggregate
  ([
  {$match: {$or: [
                  {"Comments" : {$regex : /.*smooth.*/i}},   
                  {"Comments" : {$regex : /.*good.*/i}},
                  {"Comments" : {$regex : /.*great.*/i}}
                  ]
           }
  },

  {$group: {_id : "$Comments", Count: {$sum : 1},}},

  ])
```

Comment: Any answers to this? Thanks